# Find instances of a string only if another string is found

Tags: powershell

I have a file where a 'process' is opened, then closed. This master process might have child processes but I only want to list the master process only if it has a runtime.

### File:

```
open: p1
runtime = 0:01:00
close: p1
open: p2
open: a1
open: a2
close: a1
close: a2
runtime = 0:01:00
close: p2
open: p3
close: p3
```

### Script1: This will find the master process, but also if it has no runtime

```
$file = (Get-Content "C:\#SCRIPTS\test.txt")
$strOpen = 'Open'
$strTime = 'Runtime'

$file | ForEach-Object {
    $LINE = $_

    if ("$LINE" -like "*$strOpen*") {
        $strFound1 = (($LINE).Split(":")).Trim(" ")
        $process = $strFound1[1]
        write-host  "Process Started: $process"
        
        }
    if ("$LINE" -like "*$strTime*") {
        $strFound2 = (($LINE).Split("=")).Trim(" ")
        $time = $strFound2[1]
        write-host  "Elapsed Time: $time"
    }
}
```

### Output1:

```
Process Started: p1
Elapsed Time: 0:01:00
Process Started: p2
Elapsed Time: 0:01:00
Process Started: p3
```

### Script2: This only finds the first master process with a run time, but then seems to exit the script. How do I make it continue to the next item in the loop without exiting the loop?

```
$file = (Get-Content "C:\#SCRIPTS\test.txt")
$strOpen = 'Open'
$strTime = 'Runtime'
$strClose = 'Close'
$foundFirst = $false

$file | ForEach-Object {
    $LINE = $_

    if ($foundFirst -eq $false) {
        if ("$LINE" -like "*$strOpen*") {
            $foundFirst = $true
            $strFound1 = (($LINE).Split(":")).Trim(" ")
            $process = $strFound1[1]
            #write-host  "Process Started: $process"
        }
    }

    if ($LINE -like "*$strClose*") {
        continue
    }

    if ("$LINE" -like "*$strTime*") {
        $strFound2 = (($LINE).Split("=")).Trim(" ")
        $time = $strFound2[1]
        write-host  "Process Opened: $process Elapsed Time: $time"
        $foundFirst = $false
        
    }
}
```

### output2:

```
Process Started: p1
Elapsed Time: 0:01:00
```

Not sure how to make this logically flow.

### Expected output

```
Process Opened: p1 Elapsed Time: 0:01:00
Process Opened: p2 Elapsed Time: 0:01:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example file you give this will find the processes with a runtime and generate an object for each one it finds:

```
Select-String -Path .\test.txt -Pattern '^runtime =.*' -Context 0,1 |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Process = $_.context.postcontext.split()[1]
            Runtime = $_.matches.value.split()[2]
        }
    }
```

The code is assuming that each `runtime` entry is immediately followed by the `close` for the appropriate process (which seems to be the case).

Example output:

```
Process Runtime
------- -------
p1      0:01:00
p2      0:01:00
```

Comment: This is amazing! Works flawlessly. That is correct, the runtime is always followed by a close.